# Saving log output file to chosen directory

Tags: java, logging

I'm trying to save a log file to the same directory where the excel file is saved and give it the same name as the excel file. Is it possible with the FileHandler?

This code generates an empty log file to the same directory as the excel file:

```
FileHandler fh;
 String logName = model.getTargetexcelFilepath() + "/" + 
        model.getExcelFileName() + ".log";

    try {  
        fh = new FileHandler(logName);  
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

        for(String temp: model.getMappedFiles()) {
            logger.info("Mapped file: " + temp + "\n");
        }
```

If I hard code the string value like this:

```
String logName = "test.log";
```

it will generate a log file with the logs I want but it gets saved to the project within Eclipse.

How do I set the name to the same as the excel file and to the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the proper permission in the desired directory then it should basically work. Check your file separator `/` or `\` or `//`. This is a comment but I cannot comment on your post because I am a new user. An [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) would be appreciated!